Are shiny roaming Pokemon visible on the overworld in Pokemon Emerald Rogue?
The romhack Pokemon Emerald Rogue 2.0 added catchable roaming Pokemon which can be seen on the overworld, similar to how they worked in Sword/Shield. Can you tell if a Pokemon will be shiny based on the overworld sprite? Or will it only appear shiny once you start fighting it?


Based on the 2.0 change log, shines will appear in the overworld

Pokémon’s shiny state is determined in the overworld, with a Legends Arceus style animation + sound effect which plays too!

